# A SPARQL query to return entities that satisfy some of the conditions

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web

I have a requirement to write a SPARQL query to return those entities that satisfy a fixed number of conditions (not always all of them). The idea is that I need to get all those entities that satisfy say 2 out of the 4 conditions provided. I am writing the following query

```
SELECT ?ent WHERE {
    BIND(0 as ?cnt).
    OPTIONAL {
       ?ent ns:age ?age.
       FILTER(?age > 20 && ?age <= 40).
       BIND(?cnt + 1, ?cnt).
    }.
    OPTIONAL {
        ?ent ns:livesIn nst:Mauritius.
        BIND(?cnt + 1, ?cnt).
    }.
    OPTIONAL {
        ?ent ns:maritalStatus nst:Married.
        BIND(?cnt + 1, ?cnt).
    }.
    OPTIONAL {
        ?ent ns:fatherIs/ns:age ?fatherAge.
        FILTER(?fatherAge > 55 && ?fatherAge <= 80).
        BIND(?cnt + 1, ?cnt).
    }
} HAVING(?cnt > 2)
```

Am I going about the problem in the correct way? Am I missing out on something? Is there a better way to solve my problem?

EDIT 1: The above mentioned query gave me an error. Now I am trying with this

```
SELECT ?ent ?cnt WHERE {
    BIND(0 as ?cnt1).
    BIND(0 as ?cnt2).
    BIND(0 as ?cnt3).
    BIND(0 as ?cnt4).
    OPTIONAL {
       ?ent ns:age ?age.
       FILTER(?age > 20 && ?age <= 40).
       BIND(1 as ?cnt1).
    }.
    OPTIONAL {
        ?ent ns:livesIn nst:Mauritius.
        BIND(1 as ?cnt2).
    }.
    OPTIONAL {
        ?ent ns:maritalStatus nst:Married.
        BIND(1 as ?cnt3).
    }.
    OPTIONAL {
        ?ent ns:fatherIs/ns:age ?fatherAge.
        FILTER(?fatherAge > 55 && ?fatherAge <= 80).
        BIND(1 as ?cnt4).
    }
    BIND((?cnt1 + ?cnt2 + ?cnt3 + ?cnt4) as ?cnt)
} ORDER BY DESC(?cnt)
```

This query returns a value of 0 under ?cnt for all records

Comment: your whole query doesn't work given illegal SPARQL syntax. did you ever try to run it?

Comment: And no, something like `SELECT * WHERE {
    BIND(0 as ?cnt).
    OPTIONAL {
       ?s :p ?o .     
       BIND(?cnt + 1 as ?cnt)
    }
}` won't work given that it's simply a left join on the variables of the `OPTIONAL` clause

Comment: You were correct about the syntax error. I have modified my query.

Comment: It is tricky when all vars in an optional are unbound. If the first block provides any solutions for ?ent then the rest of query will be restricted to only these values, so the order matter. I could suggest you to use an UNION between any two of the conditions.

Comment: Of course it gives 0. You first declare that `?cnt1`, `?cnt2`, `?cnt3`, and `?cnt4` are equal to 0, then you declare that `?cnt` is the sum of these zeros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest the following naive approach.

```sql
SELECT ?ent ?cnt WHERE {
    ?ent a foaf:Person .
    OPTIONAL {
        ?ent ns:age ?age.
        FILTER(?age > 20 && ?age <= 40).
    }
    OPTIONAL {
        ?ent ns:livesIn ?livesIn.
        FILTER (?livesIn = nst:Mauritius)
    }
    OPTIONAL {
        ?ent ns:maritalStatus ?maritalStatus.
        FILTER (?maritalStatus = nst:Married).
    }
    OPTIONAL {
        ?ent ns:fatherIs/ns:age ?fatherAge.
        FILTER(?fatherAge > 55 && ?fatherAge <= 80).
    }
    BIND(xsd:integer(bound(?age)) +
         xsd:integer(bound(?livesIn)) +
         xsd:integer(bound(?maritalStatus)) +
         xsd:integer(bound(?fatherAge))
         AS ?cnt)
    FILTER (?cnt > 2)
} ORDER BY DESC(?cnt)
```

---

There are two problems with your recent query:

- External `BIND`s override internal ones (or rather there is no join between them).
- You're starting with `OPTIONAL` (see [In SPARQL, order matters](https://wiki.blazegraph.com/wiki/index.php/SPARQL_Order_Matters)).

Comment: It is not guaranteed that foaf:Person is present for these entities ...

Comment: Yes, of course. But something should be present. I'll explain (but you obviously know).

Comment: What you suggested works. But I was not able to cast the `bound` to an integer. So I used an if condition instead. Something like `if(bound(?age), 1, 0)`

Answer (score 2):

Probably should elaborate more on the use of UNION that I suggested in the above comment. e.g. to retrieve everything that matches the first condition AND at lest one of the rest, OR the solutions where second condition holds AND at least one of the other two OR solutons where the last two are present together, so something like that:

```
SELECT ?ent WHERE {
{
    ?ent ns:age ?age.
    FILTER(?age > 20 && ?age <= 40).
    {
        ?ent ns:livesIn nst:Mauritius.
    } union {
        ?ent ns:maritalStatus nst:Married.
    } union {
            ?ent ns:fatherIs/ns:age ?fatherAge.
            FILTER(?fatherAge > 55 && ?fatherAge <= 80).
    }
} union {
    ?ent ns:livesIn nst:Mauritius.
    {
        ?ent ns:maritalStatus nst:Married.
    } union {
            ?ent ns:fatherIs/ns:age ?fatherAge.
            FILTER(?fatherAge > 55 && ?fatherAge <= 80).
    }    
} union {
    ?ent ns:maritalStatus nst:Married.
    ?ent ns:fatherIs/ns:age ?fatherAge.
    FILTER(?fatherAge > 55 && ?fatherAge <= 80).
  }
}
```

The other possible approach is to use GROUP BY over ?ent, but that will work only if the solutions per ?ent in each OPTIONAL block is exactly one, then the query is a simple UNION between all conditions and then using HAVING to filter out what is not desired:

```
SELECT ?ent WHERE {
{
    ?ent ns:age ?age.
    FILTER(?age > 20 && ?age <= 40).
} union {
    ?ent ns:livesIn nst:Mauritius.
} union {
    ?ent ns:maritalStatus nst:Married.
} union {
        ?ent ns:fatherIs/ns:age ?fatherAge.
        FILTER(?fatherAge > 55 && ?fatherAge <= 80).
}
} GROUP BY ?ent
HAVING (count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: I don't understand why you need the `BIND(1 as ?cnt)` in your second query. It's superflous given that you could simply do `count(*)` to count the triples per each entity.

Comment: Yes, it is redundant.